# pyspark dataframe retrieve the first value in each sequence within an ordered column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Edited with a new example for clarify

The following data

```
+------+---------+-----------+
|    ID| location| loggedTime|
+------+---------+-----------+
|    67|      312|   12:09:00|    
|    67|      375|   12:23:00|     
|    67|      375|   12:25:00|     
|    67|      650|   12:26:00|     
|    75|      650|   12:27:00|     
|    75|      650|   12:29:00|     
|    75|      800|   12:30:00|     
+------+---------+-----------+
```

should yield the below, where we compare each row to the previous column 'ID' and 'location'. I need to log each time ID was logged at a different location. They can visit the same location again later in the sequence, therefore dropDupicates on ID and location isn't possible

```
+------+---------+-----------+
|    ID| location| loggedTime|
+------+---------+-----------+
|    67|      312|   12:09:00|    
|    67|      375|   12:23:00|     
|    67|      650|   12:26:00|     
|    75|      650|   12:27:00|     
|    75|      800|   12:30:00|     
+------+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [Window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html) ordered by `loggedTime` can be used to get the `location` from the previous row. Then the rows where the current and the previous `location` are the same can be filtered out:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

w=Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("loggedTime")
df.withColumn("prev_location", F.lag("location").over(w)) \
  .filter("prev_location is null or location <> prev_location") \
  .drop("prev_location") \
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+-------------------+
| ID|location|         loggedTime|
+---+--------+-------------------+
| 67|     312|1970-01-01 00:09:00|
| 67|     375|1970-01-01 00:23:00|
| 67|     650|1970-01-01 00:26:00|
| 75|     650|1970-01-01 00:27:00|
| 75|     800|1970-01-01 00:30:00|
+---+--------+-------------------+
```

Comment: There was another column that i had not included to try and simplify the question. It ended up, messing up the outcome. There was an ID column also, where it needed to be ordered based on ID first, then the location. This provides an excellent explanation and point for me to build upon though

Comment: I have added the `ID` column to my answer. Using this column as partition column for the window should improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

how about useing group by?

```
df = df.groupBy(col("id"), col("location")).agg(min(col("loggedTime")))
```

Comment: That looks like it might work also, but I haven't tried it out.