# Pyspark: comparing elements of RDD

Tags: pyspark, comparison, rdd

Similar to the question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416708/pyspark-dataframe-retrieve-the-first-value-in-each-sequence-within-an-ordered-co) about working with DFs, how can I retrieve the first element in each sequence, but in this situation using RDDs? I want to compare each item to the 1 previous. Items that repeat later in the sequence are acceptable ie `(67,375, 14:20:14)` might appear later in the RDD and should be kept.

Input

```
(67, 312, 12:09:00)
(67, 375, 12:23:00)  
(67, 375, 12:25:00)    
(67, 650, 12:26:00)
(75, 650, 12:27:00)  
(75, 650, 12:29:00)    
(75, 800, 12:30:00)    
(67, 375, 14:20:14)
```

Output

```
(67, 312, 12:09:00)
(67, 375, 12:23:00)  
(67, 650, 12:26:00)
(75, 650, 12:27:00)  
(75, 800, 12:30:00)  
(67, 375, 14:20:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work. But, my only concern is that, you cannot rely on the order of the output the transformation on rdd will result in. So, to retain the order, I strongly suggest you to sort by a column, here you fortunately have the timestamp column.

If you are not planning to sort by timestamp, then please go with dataframe windowing approach. Even there, you might need sorting :)

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(67, 312, "12:09:00"),
(67, 375, "12:23:00"), 
(67, 375, "12:25:00"),   
(67, 650, "12:26:00"),
(75, 650, "12:27:00"), 
(75, 650, "12:29:00"),   
(75, 800, "12:30:00") ])

# Fix 1st two columns as keys.
rdd_fix_keys = rdd.map(lambda x:((x[0],x[1]),(x[2])))

# Group the values of similar keys.
rdd_group_by_key = rdd_regroup_keys.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:(x,y))

# Pick first occurence of the grouped values, as per your requirement.
rdd_pick_first_occurence = rdd_group_by_key.map(lambda x:(x[0], x[1][0]) if not isinstance(x[1], str) else x)

# Sort by timestamp.
rdd_pick_first_occurence.map(lambda x:(x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1])).sortBy(lambda x: x[2]).collect()
```

[image]

[image]

***Note: The order is changed here.***

[image: Note: The order is changed here]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely close, but I should have included the repeating values that I needed to keep in the example. If ordered by time, the second occurance of 67, 375 
 -> (67,375,  14:20:14) should be kept also. I've edited the example

Comment: @Tony Russa, I would like to know, what stops you from converting this RDD to Data Frame and doing these transformations? If conversion is ok, let me know, we can solve it easily with DF.

Comment: Hi Jim. Yeah, I could easily convert it to a dataframe and do it that way. The reason I'm trying to solve it via RDDs is that I'm new to pyspark, and I'm doing a few problems using both RDDs and Dataframes, to try and understand the differences and use cases that each are more suited to, or if DFs should be used in every situation. It looks like this is defintely one of those use cases that DFs are definitely more suited to

Comment: Its still doable in RDDs, writing complex user defined functions. But, why strain yourself when another comfortable API like dataframe is available for your requirement. IMHO, best to use DFs instead of RDDs, when you data is structured and is accompanied with a schema. HINT: You can use windowing, lead, lag functions to achieve this in Dataframes. All the Best!

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it solved your initial problem or gave an idea for doing so.